# CruseControl.Net mail check-in

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

How can I configure the "publisher" section in ccnet.config file in order to send email **only** to person who checked-in when the build fails?

Thanks,
John.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can "out of the box".

You'll have to write your own publisher...and piggy back on "FailureUsers".

https://github.com/ccnet/CruiseControl.NET/blob/master/project/core/IIntegrationResult.cs

```
    // Users who contributed modifications to a series of failing builds:
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the failure users.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value></value>
    /// <remarks></remarks>
    ArrayList FailureUsers { get; } // This should really be a Set but sets are not available in .NET 1.1
```

Here is the tech-spec:

http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Custom+Builder+Plug-in

Here is an example of someone who wrote one....

http://krisselden.com/2007/01/29/adding-a-custom-cruisecontrolnet-publisher/